# Talend tOutputFile provokes error when saving with double quotes

Tags: java, filenames, talend

Hard to understand the title I know. I am importing keywords from a CSV File in a format like this:

"Business Intelligence";
"Big Data";

with doublequotes. Afterwards I do a HTTP GET Request with each of these Keywords like this:

```
"http://www.stepstone.de/5/ergebnisliste.html?ke="+ context.keywordname +"&li=1000000"
```

My outputfile does this:

```
"C:/Talend/workspace/WEBCRAWLER/output/keywords_" + context.keywordname +".txt"
```

Obviously you can't write double quotes in the file name. What can I do as a workaround?
I already tried adding " in the get request, but it didn't work out unfortunatelly!

Thank you!

Comment: What error are you getting? And can you try printing to the console the HTTP GET request and the file name you are outputting?

Comment: As an aside, best practice suggests that you should use the globalMap for passing data around a job and only use context variables to pass data to another job.

Comment: I get the error that a file can't be created with the name keywords_"Business Intelligence".txt - obviously due to the quotes. How can i print to console? Thanks

Comment: Use a tJava component with the line `System.out.println("C:/Talend/workspace/WEBCRAWLER/output/keywords_" + context.keywordname +".txt");`. My feeling is you shouldn't have double quotes in the first part either and you should be parsing that out in a prior step. It's hard to tell without seeing your full job though. Screenshots of everything and actual error messages or even an exported job would help.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML encode on the files:

```
"Business Intelligence";"Big Data";
```

would become

> `&quot;Business Intelligence&quot;;&quot;Big Data&quot;;`

I used the following site: http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/HTMLEncode/encode.aspx

Unfortunately there's no easy way to that that in Talend, however you could try to use:
java.net.URLEncoder
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: Thank you, I tried this. Thing is, the file separates by semicolon - which makes &quot";" a problem. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create file name with keyword then you can replace/remove keywords double quotes using replace function please check below code, i think this will work for you.

```
"C:/Talend/workspace/WEBCRAWLER/output/keywords_" + context.keywordname.replace("\"\"", "") +".txt"
```